# NullPointer on an Android layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

when trying to edit a layout in the GUI. I stopped working on this project a while ago, but I'm coming back to it, but it seems uneditable. Any tips?

The Error Log says

```
"eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_06
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product



Error
Tue Dec 04 06:08:55 EST 2012
text_frag.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.tearDown(RenderAction.java:250)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.release(RenderAction.java:218)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:338)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:486)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1538)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1284)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1768)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1706)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
"
```

The xml being complained about:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_ide"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container_ide"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/grad" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="timer"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/luck" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pwd_statuss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="attachAlert"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/type_icon_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linerlayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:hint="Your Message (Up to 1500 Chracters)"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#585858"
        android:textColorLink="#000000"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is no code given, where to find exception?

Comment: What code you have on RenderAction.java:250 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means... sorry. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Eclipse and the Android plugin?

Comment: Yes, I feel like that's what could be the issue.

Comment: Is this an error produced by Eclipse or your app? It seems this is just one of the several random errors produced by Eclipse or ADT. Restarting Eclipse usually helps. Update of the ADT is also a good idea.

Comment: I have restarted eclipse and updated the SDK. Looking into updating the ADT now.

Comment: Updating the ADT fixed it! Thanks! Usually SDK Manager tells me to update ADT after I update SDK, but the one time it didn't remind me... I forgot. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the ADT fixed it! Note to self... don't update SDK tools without updating ADT.